# WordPress and Git: How does Git interact with your IDE?

Tags: version-control, git

Everyone has been telling me I should use Git. What I don't understand is how git interacts with your IDE. Say i'm developing on Dreamweaver, and I switch branches, my IDE isn't going to reflect that so how do I get the two aligned? Plugins? = more complicated than simple FTP sync ...

Or am I missing something?

Comment: AlxVallejo  it depends on the IDE ... many of them don't support Git and this is probably more of a personal question about tools then WordPress specific.  For what it's worth. I use SourceTree and Bitbucket for Git  but I use Coda2 as my IDE

Comment: This Question will very likely be closed as it has nothing to do with WordPress

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know Dreamweaver at all, but it certainly has the ability to know when an underlying file has changed, yes? Suppose you open an html file in Dreamweaver. Suppose you open it also in vim or TextWrangler; were you to save it in vim or TextWrangler, would it throw an alert to reload the file in Dreamweaver?

If so, that's all changing branches will do.

Unfortunately, Dreamweaver doesn't have [direct git integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149607/877115) the way, say, Eclipse or IntelliJ do.

Comment: I see, so the integration just makes that "alert" process more pleasant and manageable I'm assuming

Comment: Yes, but the same is true of any version control system integration. If your IDE doesn't strongly support version control one way or another, that is reason alone to pick a new IDE. I'm only half joking about that.